# celery: error: unrecognized arguments: worker -A test_tasks -l info -c 5

Tags: python, redis, celery

I am getting strange error using Celery, and I am running it the same way I was 30 minutes ago. I have been working on several files in the project, but for some reason all of a sudden I get

```
[virtual_assistant] cchilders:~/projects/virtual_assistant 
$ celery worker -A test_tasks -l info -c 5
usage: celery [-h] [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
              [--noauth_local_webserver]
              [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
              [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
celery: error: unrecognized arguments: worker -A test_tasks -l info -c 5
```

This is the same command I used to run a couple celery files, based on http://agiliq.com/blog/2015/07/getting-started-with-celery-and-redis/

The code is here https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/virtual_assistant

I've seen other answers about this that Celery's arg parsing is broken, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Where is your `test_tasks` file?

Comment: Hi Chillar, I overwrote that version using `schedule`. I'd still like to understand. The very first commit, `3cda4fc`, of that `virtual_assistant` repo has the code with the celery issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be caused by a library or other file you've imported that uses argparse. If you're importing a file that has something like:

```
import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
```

then celery's arg parsing might get clobbered and not work properly.

Comment: I gave up on celery after this and similar nonsense, so that's close enough

Comment: What is the solution to this ?

Comment: My google api client code is using that and I am getting this same error :(

Comment: @Kishan: Here's my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50455354/328469

Answer (score 0):

Something (probably `argparse`) is mutating `sys.argv` prior to celery's handling of its command line arguments (probably also with `argparse`).

To get around this, if you can isolate precisely where your celery application initialization is interacting with the offending external module (possibly with something as innocuous as an `import`), you can try to do something like this:

```
_preserved_argv = list(sys.argv[1:])
del sys.argv[1:]
irksome_library_module.jerkface_code()
sys.argv.extend(_preserved_argv)
```

My celery invocation:

`celery worker --app myapp.schedule`

...now works the way I expect it to.